# FreeBSD script to show active connections and append number remote file

Tags: bash, ssh, command-line-interface, freebsd, netscaler

I am using NetScaler FreeBSD, which recognizes many of the UNIX like commands, grep, awk, crontab… etc.

I run the following command to get the number of connected users that we have on the system

```
#> nsconmsg -g aaa_cur_ica_conn -d stats
```

OUTPUT (numbered lines):

```
Line1: Displaying current counter value information
Line2: NetScaler V20 Performance Data
Line3: NetScaler NS11.1: Build 63.9.nc, Date: Oct 11 2019, 06:17:35
Line4:
Line5: reltime:mili second between two records Sun Jun 28 23:12:15 2020
Line6: Index reltime     counter-value symbol-name&device-no
Line7:     1 2675410                 605 aaa_cur_ica_conn
…
…
```

From above output - I only need the number of connected users (represented in Line 7, 3rd column (`605` to be precise), along with the Hostname and Time (of the running script)

Now, to extract this important 3rd column number i.e. `605`, along with the hostname, and time of data collected - I wrote the following script:

```
printf '%s - %s - %s\n' "$(hostname)" "$(date '+%H:%M')" "$(nsconmsg -g aaa_cur_ica_conn -d stats | grep aaa_cur_ica_conn | awk '{print $3}')"
```

The result is perfect, showing hostname, time, and the number of connected users as follows:

```
Hostname - 09:00 – 605
```

Now can anyone please shed light on how I can:

- Run this script every day - 5am to 5pm (12hours)?
- Each time scripts runs - append a file on a remote Unix share with the output?

I appreciate this might be a bit if a challenge... however would be grateful for any bash scripts wizards out there that can create magic!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `echo "1 2204996 605 aaa_cur_ica_conn" | awk '{print $3}'` ?

Comment: To make it more clearer - I have now updated the question to including your suggestion " awk '{print $3}" thanks nbari

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a quick look into the [FreeBSD Handbook](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/) or [For People New to Both FreeBSD and UNIX®](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/articles/new-users/article.html) so that you could get familiar with the operating system and tools that could help you achieve better what you want.

For example, there is a utility/command named [`cron`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)

> The software utility cron is a time-based job scheduler in Unix-like computer operating systems.

For example, to run  something all days between **5am** to **5pm** every  **minute**, you could use something like:

```
* 05-17 * * * command
```

Try more options here: [`https://crontab.guru/#*_05-17_*_*_*`](https://crontab.guru/#*_05-17_*_*_*).

There are more tools for scheduling commands, for example `at` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_(command)) but this something you need to evaluate and read more about it.

Now regarding the command, you are using to get the "*number of connected users*", you could avoid the `grep` and just used `awk` for example:

```
awk '/aaa_cur_ica_conn/ {print $3}'
```

This will print only column 3 if line contains `aaa_cur_ica_conn`, but as before I invite you to read more about the topic so that you could bet a better overview and better understand the commands.

Last but not least, check this link [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) the better you could format, and elaborate your question the easy for others to give an answer.

Comment: Hiya nbari, really appreciate you taking the time provide feedback and learning resources... THANK YOU.

Comment: Looks like I have steep learning curve... will take a week or two to get my head round > test etc.. so will feedback asap.